# Rate module: Calculating and displaying variance and standard deviation

Tags: 7, views, rating

I would like to calculate the variance and standard deviation and display this alongside the mean 'result' in a view on a site running Drupal 7.

Wondering if anyone has any tips on how I might achieve this.

Awesome module. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Danny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this by creating a custom views field handler in a custom module.

The handler contained the simple php logic I need.

/**
 * @file
 * Definition
 */

class rate_calc_handler_result extends views_handler_field {

```
/**
* Loads additional fields.
*/
function query() {

}  

/**
* Renders the field handler.
*/
function render($values) {

// Calculate the variance and Standard Deviation
$criteria = array();
$criteria["entity_id"] = $values->nid;
$criteria["entity_type"] = "node";
$criteria["value_type"] = "points";
$criteria["tag"] = "Score";

$votes = votingapi_select_votes($criteria);
$count = count($votes);

if (!empty($votes) && ($count > 1)){

    foreach($votes as $vote){
        $sum += $vote['value'];
    }

    $mean = $sum/$count; 

    foreach($votes as $vote){

        $diff = $vote['value'] - $mean;
        $sumdiff += pow($diff, 2);
    }

    $variance = $sumdiff / $count;
    $stddev = round(sqrt($variance), 1);

}

return ($stddev);

}
```

Danny.